# How to block a thread into nop or low power status instead of switch itself outof processor

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, block

I'm writing an user-space program, in which I want to "block" a thread at some time. If I use mutex like function, the thread would be switched out of the processor. What I want is to let the thread keep on the proccessor without context switch invovled in a low power status or loop nop operations. And at some time, another thread could "wake" it up or "unblock" from the nop or low power status and continue execution. Is there any function or lib I can use?

Comment: To what end? If the thread isn't doing anything, why wouldn't you want to allow the thread to be switched out for another thread?

Comment: `while(someVolatileVar){;}`

Comment: @cdhowie if a program is sychronization-intensive, there would be lots of context switch which bring high overhead. when Hyperthreading is enalbed, I can aviod some of context switch when the under physical core is busy doing job of other processor

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming. -they guy who wrote the big books

Comment: @GradyPlayer to make it clear the program is running when Hyperhtreading is enabled, so this code would waste the cpu clock

Comment: I am pretty sure you want to waste clock, or at least waste capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good and valid question. Spin-loops like what you describe can use [`pause`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_232.html) instruction in order to enable paired hyper-thread with more resources and enable power-saving optimizations.
E.g.

```
while(condition) _mm_pause();
```

If evaluating the condition consumes more resources than necessary, repeat the `pause` several times. E.g. [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb)::[spin_mutex](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/synchronization/mutexes/spin_mutex_cls.htm) uses a backoff algorithm where each failed condition check leads to doubling the number of `pause` iterations before the next evaluation.

See also [this blog](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/tricks/spinning).

Comment: Using pause was my backup plan. In my test, pause instruction would still bring 30% performance lose for the paired hyper-thread. This why I post this question to look for better method

Comment: great. That is new to me. But if there is somthing like monitor/mwait that can make proccessor into a low power state, then it should be better. Note: mwait, as I know can only be used in kernel level.

Comment: If there would be such a thing which is more efficient than spinwait with the pause on a local flag, we would definitely use it instead.